# Setting a drawable's alpha

Tags: android

I've created a custom view that extends FrameLayout to create my own Image Button with a method to set the background image alpha, and I add 35 instances of this custom view to my Fragment.

When I call the method that sets the background image alpha, everything works, but when I try to set back to the original background image, all of the buttons have the background image with the previous alpha. Why?

Code sample:

```
public void setState(NumberState state) {
        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        Drawable drawable = null;

        switch (state) {
            case Normal:
                drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.number_button).getConstantState().newDrawable();
                mImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                break;
            case Wrong:
                drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.number_button).getConstantState().newDrawable();
                drawable.setAlpha(80);
                mImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your custom ImageButton, it seems like all instances are sharing the same drawable reference.

Comment: This method is from the custom ImageButton.  It is where I load the drawable.

Comment: In that method, the 'drawable' variable has no visibility outside that method. Perhaps you meant `drawable = null;` instead of `Drawable drawable = null;`?

Comment: I don't need to reference the Drawable instance outside this method. This method is the only one that changes the current Image view drawable.